# Node.js - Encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am integrating a payment gateway for my node.js project. They have integration kit in python and i don't have much experience in it. I ported their change from python to javascript. Is this correct ?

**Python code:**

```
def encrypt(plainText,workingKey):
        iv = 'hello'
        encDigest = md5.new ()
        encDigest.update(workingKey)
        enc_cipher = AES.new(encDigest.digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        encryptedText = enc_cipher.encrypt(plainText).encode('hex')
        return encryptedText
```

**Ported Code (Node.js):**

```
function encrypt(plainText, workingKey){
    var iv = 'hello';
    var encDigest   = crypto.createHash('md5');
    encDigest.update(workingKey);
    var enc_cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encDigest, iv);
    var encryptedText = enc_cipher.encrypt(plainText).encode('hex');
    return encryptedText;

}
```

Comment: It looks identical but some concerns: `md5` shouldn't be used in security applications IMO. And I'm not sure whether the `iv` should not be a static value... like, payment is something very sensitive;

Comment: IV should *NEVER* be static, actually should be as random as possible and should change for each encryption. Of course to decrypt, you should use the same IV used for encryption. After encryption it can be made public, without impacting security. Usually it is prefixed to the ciphertext.

Comment: Have you tried random testing to see if you get identical ciphertext output from the python and js versions?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not working? The only possible issue I can see is async vs sync. For example the `var encDigest   = crypto.createHash('md5');` may not be resolved when `encDigest.update(workingKey);` gets fired.